# Connecting to a remote mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, connection

How would I connect to [the demo phpmyadmin server](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/) in php? My code looks like this.

```
<?php
$host = 'http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/';
$dbname = 'shubham';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

// Attempt to connect to database.
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

but I get this as my error

```
QLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'http://www.demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/' (1)
```

Comment: a couple of things: 1) Is the server running on the default port? 2) You can't connect via HTTP, unless you want to see PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two things:

- the demo phpMyAdmin front-end that is backed by a db server and db/schema
- the db server and schema itself

PDO needs the latter, the db server itself.

Inspecting the front-end code of the demo, I don't see anything in there that would give us the actual connection details for the db server. And that's as I would expect: I find it hard to believe that the makers/maintainers of the phpMyAdmin demo would make their actual db server available for public remote connections.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Are there any db servers available for public remote connections? I just want to show off an example.

Comment: Typically, you would configure your own db server on your own hosting infrastructure. In my experience, most shared hosting does _not_ accept remote connections; they limit connections solely to clients from within their hosting environment. Hosting using a virtual private server (VPS) is usually the way to go. I have used ServerGrove and was pleased. But are you sure you need really need _remote_ connections? If you run your demo app on your existing hosting, a db connection in that space is not remote. If you run it locally with a local db, then also not remote. Or am I misunderstanding? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

change your hostname from

```
$host = 'http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/';
```

to your original remote hostname like **eg** `$host = 'ukld.db.5510597.hostedresource.com';`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not work on HTTP

```
<?php
$host = 'demo.phpmyadmin.net';
// High chances that this is NOT your mysql hostname.
// It will not even by like /STABLE/ as you mentioned it.
$dbname = 'shubham';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

// Attempt to connect to database.
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```